# Additional EFS Access Point cannot be mounted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nfs, amazon-efs

I am using some EFS Access Points from an EC2 instance.  I had initially set up the access points I needed and can mount the original access points using the `efs` file type, eg:

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=[access-point-1-id] [efs-fs-id]:/ mnt1
```

This works and I can see and update files in the mounted file system.  I then added a new access point under the same file system. However when I attempt to mount the new access point I get the following:

```
sudo mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=[access-point-2-id] [efs-fs-id]:/ mnt2
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 804, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 757, in run
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 796, in poll_tunnel_process
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Yet the original Access Point can be mounted with no problem.

These are both under the same mount target for the subnet, which is available.  The Network Interface shows up in the EC2 console as `in-use` and the associated Security Group has the NFS port accessible.  It's certainly allowing access to the first Access Point.  My question is, why is access to the newly added Access Point denied?  Have I forgotten to add the Access point to another security list or is there something in the system I need to restart for the new Access Point to be noticed?

I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Solved:  The underlying EFS file system needed the directories in place as it does not automatically create the Access Point directories, UNLESS the optional creation POSIX user id is specified.

Comment: How do you specify  creation POSIX user id ?

Comment: This is done when creating the Access Point.

Comment: I mean, what user you use? to make paths created automatically on mount.

Comment: The user is whoever you decide needs to own the directories, you can specify the user name and group much like when you chown directories although you use the id's for the user and group.  You can also do the same for the permissions.

Comment: This section of the EFS docs is worth reading on the matter.  See the heading 'Enforcing a User Identity Using an Access Point'. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-access-points.html